# testing a function in jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, alert

Sorry, really stupid question here. If you post a question about javascript or jquery, people often say - create a jsfiddle.

So, I did. My question will be about getting divs to slide up using jquery but, I can't even get a basic javascript function to run in jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/ubq6E/

```
<div onclick="showit()">Hello</div>
function showit()
{
alert('hi');
}
```

A div, click on it to call a javascript function, but jsfiddle says the function is not defined. Can you not do this in jsfiddle?

Comment: Yes, change where the JS is included: http://jsfiddle.net/ubq6E/1/

Comment: See the second select box on the left hand side, at the top? Also inspecting the source of the result frame could give some insights. You can find more information in the documentation: http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#fiddle-settings-sidebar.

Comment: Thank you both - thought it was about time I gave up this lark.

Answer (score 10):

You've selected the default `onLoad` option in jsfiddle.

This causes the site to wrap your entire code within a callback function, meaning that your `showit` function is not a global function as required by DOM0 inline event handlers.

There are several work arounds, in my personal order of preference:

1. don't use DOM0 inline handlers, they're *really* old school - look into `element.addEventListener()` instead and separate your markup from your JS.
2. use `window.showit = function() { ... }` instead to force your function to appear in the global name space.
3. select one of the "no wrap" options

Comment: Yep!  Click the Javascript button in the javascript window and choose No Wrap - in Head.