# JSFiddler doesn't read javascript

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

Have a simple function I want to write jsfiddle, but I cannot get any javascript to work. Tried in FF and Chrome with same results.

Looked at SO posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431351/simple-example-doesnt-work-on-jsfiddle) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468350/javascript-not-running-on-jsfiddle-net) but I couldn't get it to work.

Code:

```
<input type="button" value="5 Items" onclick="test()">
<input type="button" value="6 Items" onclick="arrayOfOandZ(6)">
<input type="button" value="7 Items" onclick="arrayOfOandZ(7)">


function test() {
    alert("TEST");
}

function arrayOfOandZ (size) {
    var arrayOFOnZ[size];
    //Fill array
    for(var x = 0; x < size; x++){
        arrayOfOnZ[x] = size % 2;
    }
    alert(arrayOFOnZ.join('\n'));
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sfJLx/7/)

Comment: It's because JavaScript written in the JavaScript panel isn't accessible to in-line event-handlers (`onclick`, `onmouseover`, etc), presumably by-design. If you use unobtrusive JavaScript (so the event-handling is defined in the JavaScript panel along with the functions those handlers call), then it works fine.

Comment: @DavidThomas: Or if you change the dropdown on the left

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`. I mistakenly voted to close the question as a duplicate, but it really should be closed as *too localized*.

Comment: The new fiddle you linked too has a syntax error too: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [ `. I recommend to [read this article](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) to learn how to debug JavaScript. Arrays defined as `var arr = [];` in JavaScript. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/15543456/218196.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script (the one posted at the jsFiddle link) contains the following errors:

- You're using a undefined `$document` value and trying to call a function (`ready`) on it.
- You have a line that reads:

  ```
  alert("TEST);
  ```
- You have a line that reads:

  ```
  var arrayOFOnZ[size];
  ```

Additionally, the function gets defined only after the DOM is loaded, by default. Change the dropdown on the left from "onLoad" to "No wrap - in `<head>`", to instruct jsFiddle to append your script directly in the `<head>` tag, instead of in the `window.onload` function.

Comment: Ahh, wrong fiddle posted. I have one without that error and see the same thing (edited in question)

Comment: @PepperedLemons, in the new fiddle, you still have the last syntax error that I'm mentioning.

Comment: Still nothing. Tried to make the fiddle simple. Just an alert http://jsfiddle.net/sfJLx/9/

Comment: @PepperedLemons, this is happening because the `test()` function only gets defined *after* the DOM is loaded. Change the dropdown on the left from "onLoad" to "No wrap - in <head>", so that the script is appended as is, in the `<head>` tag, instead of in a function called at the `window.onload` event. Updated answer.

Comment: @Peppered: In your new series of fiddles, you are defining the functions in the `load` event handlers, which makes your question a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/15543456/218196.

Answer (score 1):

Update your fiddle to use `no wrap - in <head>` or `no wrap in <body>` or jsFiddle will wrap the script by default into a `window.onload`. Which causes the elements to render first and as the `onclick` is rendered the script does not exists yet as it only gets added after the window is loaded, like this:

```
<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>- jsFiddle demo</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lib/dummy.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
        <style type="text/css">
</style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //<![CDATA[ 
            window.onload = function() {
                function test() {
                    alert("TEST");
                }

                function arrayOfOandZ(size) {
                    var arrayOFOnZ = new Array(size);
                    //Fill array
                    for (var x = 0; x < size; x++) {
                        arrayOfOnZ[x] = size % 2;
                    }
                    alert(arrayOFOnZ.join('\n'));
                }
            } //]]>
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="button" value="5 Items" onclick="test()">
        <input type="button" value="6 Items" onclick="arrayOfOandZ(6)">
        <input type="button" value="7 Items" onclick="arrayOfOandZ(7)">
    </body>

</html>
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sfJLx/8/) - Fixed settings in fiddle

---

`no wrap in <head>` for example renders the script directly into the `head` without the `window.onload` wrapper making it available immediately. Therefore when the elements get rendered the script exists, like this:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>- jsFiddle demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lib/dummy.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
    <style type="text/css">
</style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[ 

        function test() {
            alert("TEST");
        }

        function arrayOfOandZ(size) {
            var arrayOFOnZ = new Array(size);
            //Fill array
            for (var x = 0; x < size; x++) {
                arrayOfOnZ[x] = size % 2;
            }
            alert(arrayOFOnZ.join('\n'));
        }
        //]]>
    </script>
</head>
```