# Selected Checkbox disables the selection of another checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

I have a reason to use checkboxes instead of radio buttons so please don't suggest I use radio buttons but need to duplicate the functionality. However when I select the Yes checkbox, it disables the No checkbox for some reason. When no is selected I want to hide the div and deselect Yes, and the opposite when I select Yes I want to show the div and uncheck NO. The only way I can select NO when Yes is checked is to uncheck it.

Working demo [Here](http://triplewww.com/cm/ckTest.html)

JS Fiddle not working [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/DivineChef/6NN6s/6/)

Javascript

```
function injure() {
     if (document.getElementById("f2").checked == true) {
         document.getElementById("LocFall").style.display="block";
         document.getElementById("f1").checked = false;
     } else {
         if (document.getElementById("f1").checked == true) {
             document.getElementById("LocFall").style.display="none";
             document.getElementById("f2").checked = false;
         }
     }
}
```

CSS

```
#LocFall {
    display:none;   
}
```

HTML

```
    <input type="checkbox" id="f1" name=""  onclick="injure();">
    <label for="f1"> No </label><BR>
    <input type="checkbox" id="f2" name=""  onclick="injure();">
    <label for="f2"> Yes</label><BR>

    <div id="LocFall">
        Show some stuff
    </div>
```

Comment: I'm interested in the reason you chose checkboxes over radio buttons anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/6NN6s/14/

```
<input type="checkbox" id="f1" name="same" onclick="injure(this);" />
<label for="f1">No</label>
<BR>
<input type="checkbox" id="f2" name="same" onclick="injure(this);" />
<label for="f2">Yes</label>
<BR>
<div id="LocFall">Show some stuff</div>


function injure(cmb) {
    if (cmb.checked) {
        if(cmb.id==="f2")
        {   document.getElementById("LocFall").style.display = "block";
             document.getElementById("f1").checked = false;
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("LocFall").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("f2").checked = false;
        }
    }    
}
```

try this out, may be what you need.

Comment: Excellent I figured out I had to change the HTML function to onclick="injure(this);" Thank you.

Comment: Now what if the DIV is visible and I want to uncheck Yes or id="f2" I also want to hide the DIV.

Answer (score 1):

In Fiddle change on the left in second drop-down list 'onLoad' to 'no wrap - in `<head>`'.

Comment: What? there are no drop down lists.

Comment: This is the problem. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/6NN6s/13/) you have an updated fiddle with that option selected  and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15543456/testing-a-function-in-jsfiddle) more info

Answer (score 0):

Split `injure` into a different function for each; if you choose `No`, then you cannot choose `Yes` because of the way your function is set up - the first condition will always evaluate as `true`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem stems from not knowing which checkbox was actually clicked inside the function. As it is there's only two different ways the function can respond: one if f1 is checked and one if f2 is checked. The problem is there's actually more possible states that you're trying to represent.

1. State 1: Nothing checked, user clicks f1 or f2
2. State 2: f1 checked, f2 clicked
3. State 3: f2 checked, f1 clicked

Your code handles the first state fine but it can't deal properly with the second ones. If you split your code into two seperate functions to handle each box then you'll have all the necessary information to write correct decision logic.

There's also the states of clicking the same box, but they are simple and your code handles them already.

Comment: Yes I'll have to create separate functions.