# JS only works in <script> tags but not when in external file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I've tried making a little validation tool for myself but the problem is that it only works when it's on the same page as where the function is being called on, other than that it works as intended.

```
<script>
        function checkPhone() {
            var phone_ = document.getElementById('phone_no').value;
            var phonefn = phone_.charCodeAt(0); 

            if(phone_.length > 0){ 
            if (phone_.length != 11 || phonefn != 48) { 
                $("#phone_no").removeClass('input_style');
                $("#phone_no").removeClass('valid');
                $("#phone_no").removeClass('invalid');

                $("#phone_no").addClass('invalid');
            } else {
                $("#phone_no").removeClass('input_style');
                $("#phone_no").removeClass('valid');
                $("#phone_no").removeClass('invalid');

                $("#phone_no").addClass('valid');
            }

        }else{$("#phone_no").removeClass('valid');$("#phone_no").removeClass('invalid');}}
</script>

<form name="form" id="form" method="POST">
    <label>Phone Number:</label>
    <input id="phone_no" class="input_style" name="phone_no" onBlur="checkPhone()"></input>
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3763886t/1/

Comment: How are you loading the external js?

Comment: Move your calling script tag to the bottom of your html.

Comment: We can't tell you what is wrong with the code when you put it in an external file if you only show us how you put it inline!

Comment: @Manu — Why? I don't see what difference that would make with this JS.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande bottom of page after loading jquery

Comment: `language="javascript"` — You should avoid writing HTML 3.2 now it is the twenty first century.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks, edited

Comment: Because the javascript would load before the html, resulting in undefined.

Comment: @Manu — What would be undefined?

Comment: look at the console output (F12)

Comment: @Quentin The `phone_no` element? Im not sure but I had this problem before.

Comment: @Manu — The JavaScript statement that tries to access it is in a function and won't be evaluated until that function is called. That function won't be called until the `onblur` function is called, that function can't be called before `phone_no` is defined since it is embedded on that element.

Comment: On one hand, you have `document.getElementById('phone_no')`; and on the other; you use `$("#phone_no")` judiciously.

Comment: @hjpotter92 — Which is inconsistent, but doesn't explain why the code as shown works but the code with the script in an external file (which we can't see) doesn't work.

Comment: @WazedH, _bottom of page after loading jquery_ you use inline click handler, so function in handler should be defined before, so try include file with this function in head

Comment: @Quentin Thanks! I didn't realise that.

Comment: @Grundy — It **is** defined before in the code in the question.

Comment: @Quentin, OP say that is _not_ work in external, it not work because _external_ file add _after_ adding handler in html

Comment: @Grundy — That wouldn't make a difference unless they were somehow interacting with the input in the (probably) tiny amount of time between the input being rendered and the rest of the JS loading.

Comment: @Wazed H — Please show us your *broken* code so that we can stop speculating and see what the problem actually is.

Comment: Error messages are useful too. Show the Console output!

Comment: The code in my post above works but [this](https://jsfiddle.net/c9k1dbqj/1/) does not

Comment: @WazedH — Are you specifically asking why it doesn't work in JSFiddle? Or is your problem with a stand alone page that you are trying to reproduce in JS Fiddle to show us?

Comment: If the former, then your question is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15543456/testing-a-function-in-jsfiddle

Comment: @Quentin It doesn't work on either, I'm just using JSFiddle because I'm not sure if I can paste the whole form in the comments.

Comment: @WazedH, your sample with file work ok: http://plnkr.co/edit/KsbcKWh3FwUaAEXjadlv?p=preview

Comment: @Quentin, you right, i try it in plunkr and all seems ok :-)

Comment: @WazedH — Well, the reason the code you've shared with us doesn't work is described in the duplicate question. We can't tell why your stand alone code doesn't work because you still haven't shown it to us. The proper place for it is *edited into your question* though, not posted as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try binding your event handler in Javascript instead of in your HTML:

```
<form name="form" id="form" method="POST">
  <label>Phone Number:</label>
  <input id="phone_no" class="input_style" name="phone_no" />
</form>

<script language="javascript">
  function checkPhone() {
    var $phone = $(this);
    var phone_ = $phone.val();
    var phonefn = phone_.charCodeAt(0);

    if (phone_.length > 0) {
      if (phone_.length != 11 || phonefn != 48) {
        $phone.removeClass('input_style');
        $phone.removeClass('valid');
        $phone.removeClass('invalid');

        $phone.addClass('invalid');
      } else {
        $phone.removeClass('input_style');
        $phone.removeClass('valid');
        $phone.removeClass('invalid');

        $phone.addClass('valid');
      }

    } else {
      $phone.removeClass('valid');
      $phone.removeClass('invalid');
    }
  }

  $('#phone_no').on('blur', checkPhone);
</script>
```

Comment: This worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do not add behavior in your html. Add it using javascript directly.

Use Jquery ready function to attach your event handler.

Jquery allow adding or removing multiple class and allow to chain calls (fluent api) :

```
function checkPhone() {
    var input = $(this);
    var phone_ = input.val();
    var phonefn = phone_.charCodeAt(0);

    if (phone_.length > 0) {
        if (phone_.length != 11 || phonefn != 48) {
            input.removeClass('input_style valid')
                .addClass('invalid');
        } else {
            input.removeClass('input_style invalid')
                .addClass('valid');
        }
    } else {
        input.removeClass('valid invalid');
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    $("#phone_no").on('blur', checkPhone);
});
```

The updated fiddler :  https://jsfiddle.net/royto/kukre5vo/