# Javascript to show content if checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, html

In this Fiddle I have made script that should show the form if the checkbox is checked but I can't make it work. It says that the function is unknown variable.

Html

```
<input type="checkbox" id="_My.notFinal" onclick='toggleCheckbox();'>
<label>
   <b>Buying for someone else.</b>
</label>
<span id="LicenseCustomer" style="display:none">/*some form*/</span>
```

And javascript

```
function toggleCheckbox() {
  var lfckv = document.getElementById("_My.notFinal").checked;
  if (lfckv) {
    document.getElementById("LicenseCustomer").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("LicenseCustomer").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/00gckvxw/1/

Comment: Make sure your toggleCheckbox is under wrap head so that its globally accesible and use id="LicenseCustomer" instead of class see https://jsfiddle.net/00gckvxw/7/

Comment: @VinodLouis why did you delete your answer? It was correct

Comment: you have the spans class set to LicenseCustomer and not id. And trying to getElementById. change the class to id. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/00gckvxw/15/)

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin I know that but someone mentioned that its typo so better to write in comments and close and it make sense also

Comment: Thanks guys and sorry for the typo. :)

Comment: Was the typo the reason for this not working? The question can be closed as unreproduceable if so.

Answer (score 3):

Here it is the corrected version https://jsfiddle.net/00gckvxw/24/.

```
document.getElementById("_My.notFinal").onclick = toggleCheckbox;
```

It has to do with when the events are attached. check this out: [testing a function in jsfiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15543456/testing-a-function-in-jsfiddle).

I also changed the `span` to `div` and `class` attribute to `id`. I wouldn't recommend using `<tr>` inside a `<div>` or `<span>`, better use `id` on `<tr>` directly or use `<tbody>` if you have multiple lines.

Comment: Thanks!  this exactly worked for me.  I had to do the invoking of the method when the checkbox was clicked.   i.e. this part saved me.  ""document.getElementById("_My.notFinal").onclick = toggleCheckbox;""

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed out to include the Javascript file in your in html, because it is not able to find the function `toggleCheckbox` on click of checkbox. Also

**Also span element has class = 'LicenseCustomer', change this to id='LicenseCustomer'**
try including inline script

```
<script>
function toggleCheckbox() {
  var lfckv = document.getElementById("_My.notFinal").checked;
  console.log(lfckv);
  if (lfckv) {

    document.getElementById("LicenseCustomer").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("LicenseCustomer").style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
<input type="checkbox" id="_My.notFinal" onclick='toggleCheckbox();'>
<label><b>Buying for someone else.</b>
  <label>&nbsp;

    <span id="LicenseCustomer" style="display:none">

<tr valign=middle>
    <td class="bodycopy" align=right width=160><b>License Contact:</b>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="smallcopy" nowrap><input name="_My.LicenseContact" type="text" class="inputBox" size="32" _label="<br>License Contact"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign=middle>
    <td class="bodycopy" align=right><b> License E-mail Address:</b>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="smallcopy" nowrap><input name="_My.LicenseEmail" type="text" class="inputBox" size="32" _label="<br> License E-mail Address"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign=middle>
    <td class="bodycopy" align=right><b> License Phone:</b>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="smallcopy" nowrap><input name="_My.LicensePhone" type="text" class="inputBox" size="32" _label="<br> License Phone"></td>
    </tr>

</span>
```

Comment: There is no reason to believe that this is the problem, or that the OP has failed to include the JS.

Answer (score 0):

corrected version:

http://pastebin.com/RrMD78AG

Few mistakes i want to tell you:-
first you are using class="LicenseCustomer" and you are using document.getElementById selector (it cannot get element with class name).

second you are using onclick="toggleCheckbox();", when you calling function you does not have to use 'semicolon' at the end of a function name (its an incorrect syntax) - onclick="toggleCheckbox()" (no semicolon).

Comment: it works with a semicolon too - you can actually have more statements there

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="_My.notFinal" class='checkbox'>
    <label><b>Buying for someone else.</b>
      </label>&nbsp;

        <span class="LicenseCustomer" style="display:none">

    <tr valign=middle>
        <td class="bodycopy" align=right width=160><b>License Contact:</b>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="smallcopy" nowrap><input name="_My.LicenseContact" type="text" class="inputBox" size="32" _label="<br>License Contact"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign=middle>
        <td class="bodycopy" align=right><b> License E-mail Address:</b>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="smallcopy" nowrap><input name="_My.LicenseEmail" type="text" class="inputBox" size="32" _label="<br> License E-mail Address"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign=middle>
        <td class="bodycopy" align=right><b> License Phone:</b>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="smallcopy" nowrap><input name="_My.LicensePhone" type="text" class="inputBox" size="32" _label="<br> License Phone"></td>
        </tr>

    </span>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Below is the Javascript

```
   $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $(".checkbox").change(function() {
        if(this.checked) 
         {
            $(".LicenseCustomer").css('display','block');
        }
        else
        {
                $(".LicenseCustomer").css('display','none');
        }
    })
  });
```

Demo : https://jsbin.com/bowicivupa/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

Try to something like this.

```
function toggleCheckbox(){
     var lfckv = document.getElementById('myCheck').checked;
     if(lfckv){
        document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].setAttribute("style", "display:none");
     } else {
         document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].setAttribute("style", "display:block");
    }
}
```